# Can't import OpenZeppelin Ownable contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, error, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm following freecodecamp's solidity course but am unable to import Ownable from OpenZeppelin into my contract.

Using brownie, this is what I have so far:

[image]

and in the config.yaml file:

[image: remapping]

And when I try $ brownie compile, I get this error message:

[image]

From what I can tell, it should be working but idk, I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today and downgrading my solidity extension to a later version (0.0135) as recommended by this youtube solution fixed the issue for me:

https://youtu.be/5qTdQNCMwk8

I hope this helps the next person faced with this problem. It's not your code that's wrong, it's the extension. We move!

Answer (score 0):

Remappings can be tricky, and a little bit buggy in VSCode.

There are [a few different things](https://github.com/Cyfrin/foundry-full-course-f23/discussions/194) you can try to fix the issue:

1. Comment and un-comment the import lines. Helps "refresh" the import.
2. Restart your VS Code completely, including all opened windows. Worked for me a couple of times.
3. Try creating a 'remappings.txt' file, and add the same line without brackets and "".

For me, writing the remappings in a .txt file helped, this is how it looks in mine:

```
@openzeppelin/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/
```